# Why doesn't $1 store the complete URL when the pattern is ^(.*)$?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

There are several topics already about this. But I haven't found an answer or I still don't understand it correctly.
I know that `$1` represents the match from the first set of parentheses in the RewriteRule regex. `$1` also stores this value.
But if there is only `^(.*)$`, then it seems to work differently?

Example:
URL: `http://www.example.com/`

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What I understand:
1. `http://www.example.com/` matches with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]` and stores the match in `%1` (=example.com/).
2. go to RewriteRule because the URL matched in step 1
3. RewriteRule gets the string `http://www.example.com/`. Because of `^(.*)$`, `http://www.example.com/` matches completely and is stored in `$1`.
4.  I think this URL should appear : `https://example.com/http://www.example.com/`
What actually appears: `https://example.com/`
Why does `$1` have an empty string? It's all matched, isn't it?

Comment: `RewriteRule` directive only matchs a URL path strarting with `/` Please read the mod-rewrite documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a few misconceptions here that I'll try to address...

> ```
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

I'll ignore the `RewriteBase` directive and the second `RewriteCond` directive...

The `RewriteBase` directive does not apply here, since there are no relative path *substitution* strings (the 2nd argument to the `RewriteRule` directive).

There is no `HTTPS_HOST` server variable, only `HTTP_HOST`. See the following question on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/953020/what-is-the-difference-between-http-host-and-https-host-in-apache-htaccess-file

I think `HTTPS_HOST` has perpetuated around the internet due to a few typos/misconceptions that have been blindly copy/pasted.

`HTTP_HOST` contains the value of the `Host` HTTP request header (the *hostname*) eg. `www.example.com` or `example.com`, depending on what was requested. Hence the name `HTTP_` + `HOST`. This is the same naming convention used for all HTTP request headers. A corresponding server variable is created for each.

So, this becomes (removing the `OR` flag from the first condition):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

#### The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (eg. `^(.*)$`)

> But if there is only `^(.*)$`, then it seems to work differently?

No, it works the same. The confusion would seem to be what the `RewriteRule` *pattern* actually matches against.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only.

The URL-path is the part of the URL after the scheme + hostname and *before* the query string. eg. Given a request for `http://example.com/` then the URL-path is simply `/`. Or request `http://example.com/foo/bar?param=1` - the URL-path is `/foo/bar`.

HOWEVER, in a per-directory context like `.htaccess` (as opposed to a *server* or *virtualhost* context) the *directory-prefix* is first removed from the URL-path *before* the match occurs. (Because `.htaccess` is processed *after* the request is mapped to the filesystem and strictly speaking matches against a file-path.) The *directory-prefix* is the absolute file path of the `.htaccess` file itself and notably ends with a slash. eg. When the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root, then the directory-prefix will be something like `/var/www/user/public_html/` (the filesystem path to the document root).

So, given a request for `http://example.com/` then the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* in `.htaccess` is simply "" (empty string). Or request `http://example.com/foo/bar?param=1` - the URL-path that is matched is `foo/bar` - no slash prefix.

This is more significant when the `.htaccess` file is located in a subdirectory off the document root. For example, if the `.htaccess` file is located in the `/subdir` subdirectory and there is a request of the form `http://example.com/subdir/foo/bar`, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* will again match against just `foo/bar` (not `subdir/foo/bar` or `/subdir/foo/bar`). This is a significant difference to when `RewriteRule` directives are used in a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context. In a *server* context, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* always matches against the full URL-path, starting with a slash - there is no concept of a directory-prefix when used in a *server* context, since the directives are processed *before* the request is mapped to the filesystem.

> What I understand:
>
> 1. `http://www.example.com/` matches with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]` and stores the match in `%1` (=example.com/).
> 2. go to `RewriteRule` because the URL matched in step 1
> 3. RewriteRule gets the string `http://www.example.com/`. Because of `^(.*)$`, `http://www.example.com/` matches completely and is stored
>    in `$1`.
> 4. I think this URL should appear : `https://example.com/http://www.example.com/`

You've got the order of processing wrong. It's actually the `RewriteRule` *pattern* that is processed first. Only if the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches are the preceding `RewriteCond` (*conditions*) processed. If all the *conditions* are successful then the `RewriteRule` *substituion* (2nd argument) occurs.

So, in order, given a request for `http://www.example.com/`:

1. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$` - The resulting URL-path "" (empty string) matches the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^(.*)$`. The `$1` backreference then holds an empty string (as does the `$0` backreference - which stores the match of the entire pattern - the same in this case)
2. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$` - If the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matched in step #1 (it does in this case) then the preceding `RewriteCond` directive is processed. This matches the `Host` header eg. `www.example.com` (no `http://`) against the regex `^www\.(.*)$`. If this is successful then the `%1` backreference holds the value of the first captured group, ie. `example.com` in this example.
3. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]` - If the preceding condition(s) is successful then the *substitution* (ie. `https://%1/$1`) in the `RewriteRule` directive occurs. ie. `https://example.com/` - `%1` is `example.om` from the captured group in the last matched *CondPattern* and `$1` is an empty string, from the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Other notes:

- Due to the order of processing, it is naturally more efficient to do as much pattern matching in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* as possible, instead of relying on preceding `RewriteCond` directives. (A common misconception that `RewriteCond` directives are processed first - that is not the case.)

- Due to the order of processing, you can use `$n` backreferences in the *TestString* (first) argument of the preceding `RewriteCond` directives. (This wouldn't be possible if the directives were literally processed top-down.)
- The `%n` back references are only from the **last matched** *CondPattern*. This is important to consider if you have multiple *conditions*.